# Задачка на создание простого GUI

Tags: java, swing, gui

Задача:

- Создать окно с полями ввода, куда будет вводиться текст;
- Местом для картинки;
- Кнопкой, при нажатии на которую будет открываться второе окно.

Вот такая нужна картинка

[image: вот она]

Код вот такой пока:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class View1 extends JFrame
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new View1();
}

//  CONSTRUCTOR
public View1()
{

    super("View 1");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    // START
    JLabel labelStart = new JLabel("Введите данные: НАЧАЛО МАРШРУТА");
    add(labelStart);

    JTextField textFieldStartStreet = new JTextField();
    add(textFieldStartStreet);

    JTextField textFieldStartHouse = new JTextField();
    add(textFieldStartHouse);

    JTextField textFieldStartIndex = new JTextField();
    add(textFieldStartIndex);

    JTextField textFieldStartCity = new JTextField();
    add(textFieldStartCity);

    // END
    JLabel labelEnd = new JLabel("Введите данные: КОНЕЦ МАРШРУТА");
    add(labelEnd);

    JTextField textFieldEndStreet = new JTextField();
    add(textFieldEndStreet);

    JTextField textFieldEndHouse = new JTextField();
    add(textFieldEndHouse);

    JTextField textFieldEndIndex = new JTextField();
    add(textFieldEndIndex);

    JTextField textFieldEndCity = new JTextField();
    add(textFieldEndCity);


    JButton button = new JButton("Сохранить");
    add(button);

    // ADD LISTENERS TO COMPONENTS
    button.addActionListener(new MyActionListener1());

    // ENDCONFIGURATION AFTER VIEW IST BUILD
    setLocation(100, 100);
    setSize(700, 700);
    setVisible(true);

}

public class MyActionListener1 implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        new View2();
    }
}

}
```

Окно создаётся, но расположение элементов сильно хромает. 
Что нужно ещё добавить чтобы получилось как на картинке к заданию?

Answer (score 4):

Тебе не хватает [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) + [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Panel.html).

Собственно тебе надо разбить свой каркас на мелкие панельки, примерно как на картинке. Далее комбинируя `BoxLayout'ы` с вертикальной/горизонтальной направленностью можно довольно легко добиться ожидаемого результата. В качестве контейнера для `BoxLayout'а` подойдёт простейший `JPanel`.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]